# Geometric picture of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: general-topology, absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory

So when we complete $\mathbb{Q}$ wrt to the Euclidean abs. value, we have a nice geometric picture of filling a line (the real line) with the missing points that are almost everywhere. Is there an nice geometric analogue so that we can picture the completion $\mathbb{Q}_p$ wrt to the $p$-adic abs. value?

Comment: It is kinda hard, the $p$-adic fields are weirder than $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, every point of a ball is its center, or two balls or either disjoint or one in the other. I think it is better to look at the $p$-adic integers which are sums $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_kp^k$, and to say that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the field of fractions of this ring.

Comment: Topologically (no group and ring structure) $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is just an infinite tree where each node has $p$ children. $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is the same except that one node is labeled as "midpoint" and there is no root because the tree is infinite backward as well. The topological/tree picture isn't very useful for understanding the embedding $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Some visualization ideas for p-adics: https://thekerneltrip.com/python/p-addic-numbers-visualization, https://mathoverflow.net/q/51905/27465, http://www.nt.th-koeln.de/fachgebiete/mathe/knospe/p-adic/, https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-the-towering-p-adic-numbers-work-20201019/, https://im.icerm.brown.edu/portfolio/seeing-p-adics/.

Comment: Just like how digits of rational numbers eventually repeat in $\mathbb{R}$, digits of rational numbers in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ also eventually repeat. From the tree perspective, this means the rational numbers have an eventually repeating path descending down to the "infinite leaves" at the bottom, while elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ don't. So one way you can think of the completion as is filling in all the arbitrary paths downwards into the tree, which happen to be arbitrarily well approximated by paths that eventually repeat.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2$ is the Cantor set.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a picture, described in words.

First, a general element of $\mathbb Q_p$ can be written as a bi-infinite sequence of the form
$$\ldots a_i  \ldots a_1 a_0 . a_{-1} a_{-1} \ldots a_{-k} \ldots
$$
where $a_i \in \{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ for each $i$, and $a_i$ is eventually zero as one goes far enough to the right (i.e. there exists $j$ such that $a_i = 0$ if $i<j$). What that notation represents, of course, is the standard infinite series representation of an element of $\mathbb Q_p$:
$$\sum_{i \ge j} a_i p^i
$$
Think of that notation like decimal notation where $a_i \in \{0,\ldots,9\}$ for each $i$, except that in decimal notation one instead requires that that the $a_i$'s are all zero if one goes far enough to the left, and instead of a "decimal point" we have something called a "$p$-adic point".

Now let's turn that sequence notation into a picture, which I invite you to draw. It will be a drawing of an infinite tree. The "ends" of this tree will form the field $\mathbb Q_p$

I'll start by describing the *$\mathbb Z_p$ tree* whose ends form the ring of integers
$$\mathbb Z_p = \left\{\sum_{i \ge 0} a_i p^i\right\}
$$
First draw a single vertex labelled $.0$

Then draw $p$ segments extending upwards from the vertex $.0$ whose upper vertices are labelled by appending $0,1,...,p-1$ to the label $.0$ giving labels
$$0.0 \qquad 1.0 \qquad 2.0 \qquad\ldots\qquad (p-1).0
$$
From each of those vertices draw $p$ segments extending upwards, appending $0,1,...,p-1$. For example, extending upwards from $0.0$ are $p$ segments whose upper vertices are labelled
$$00.0 \qquad 10.0 \qquad 20.0 \qquad\ldots\qquad (p-1)0.0
$$
and extending upwards from $1.0$ are $p$ segments whose upper vertices are labelled
$$01.0 \qquad 11.0 \qquad 21.0 \qquad\ldots\qquad (p-1)1.0
$$
After doing this you will now have a total of $p^2$ segments of length $2$ extending upwards from the vertex $.0$

Continue this recursively: from a vertex labelled $a_i....a_0.0$, there are $p$ segments extending upwards labelled
$$0a_i....a_0.0 \qquad 1a_i....a_0.0 \qquad 2a_i....a_0.0 \qquad \cdots \qquad (p-1)a_i....a_0.0
$$
Taking the union over $i=0,\ldots,\infty$ one obtains the *$\mathbb Z_p$ tree*, an infinite tree extending upward from the vertex $0.$

Elements of $\mathbb Z_p$ are in one-to-one correspondence with infinite rays in the $\mathbb Z_p$ tree that extend upwards from their base vertex $0.$.

The actual elements of $\mathbb Z_p$ can themselves can be visualized geometrically as the "space of ends" of the tree. In the case $n=2$ one pretty much gets the standard picture of the middle thirds Cantor set (known to represent infinite trinity numbers of the form $.b_1 b_2 b_3 ...$ where $b_i \in \{0,2\}$, so one obtains $\mathbb Z_2$ from that representation by replacing each $2$ with at $1$ and reflecting the representation across $.$)

One thing that pops out of this picture is the embedding $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z_p$. The additive identity is just the leftmost ray starting from $0.$, namely $\ldots000000.$ More generally the non-negative integers $\mathbb Z_{\ge 0} = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ consist of all rays starting at $0.$ that, above some point, always takes the leftmost segment heading upwards, i.e. the segment corresponding to appending another $0$. The negative integers $\mathbb Z_{<0} = \{-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}$ are similarly described, namely all rays starting at $0.$ which, above some point, always take the rightmost segment heading upwards, corresponding to appending $p-1$ (thanks to @TorstenSchoeneberg for this point).

With this description of $\mathbb Z$, it's fun to try to visualize three operations: adding $+1$; additive inversion; and multiplication by $p$.

Using this geometric description of $\mathbb Z_p$, the geometric description of the whole of $\mathbb Q_p$ now proceeds by another recursion extending in the downwards direction.

For the first step of the downward recursion, off to the right of the vertex $.0$ place $p-1$ more vertices in a row, altogether labelled
$$.0 \qquad .1 \qquad .2 \qquad\cdots\qquad .(p-1)
$$
Extending downwards from each vertex in this row draw $p$ edges ending at a **common** vertex labelled $.00$ and then atop each of the vertices in this row attach separate copies of the $\mathbb Z_p$ tree extending upwards. One now the *$p^{-1} \cdot \mathbb Z_p$ tree*, representing
$$p^{-1} \cdot \mathbb Z_p = \left\{\sum_{i \ge -1} a_i p^i\right\}
$$
And now continue the recursion, representing the increasing sequence of inclusions
$$\mathbb Z_p \subset p^{-1} \cdot \mathbb Z_p \subset p^{-2} \cdot \mathbb Z_p \subset
$$
as an increasing sequence of inclusions of trees and of their ends.

I'll say the first few words of the 2nd step of the downward recursion: off to the right of the vertex $.00$, place $p-1$ additional vertices, altogether labelled
$$.00 \qquad .01 \qquad .02 \qquad \ldots \qquad .0(p-1)
$$
and then, atop each of those vertices, attach separate copies of the $p^{-1} \cdots \mathbb Z_p$ tree .........

Answer (score 2):

Of course $\mathbb Z_p$ is a self-similar fractal.  The whole is made up of $p$ parts, each with radius shrunk by factor $1/p$, and so on.

[image: three adid]  Image by [Heiko Knospe](http://www.nt.th-koeln.de/fachgebiete/mathe/knospe/p-adic/)

The $3$-adic integers are in the gray circle.  That is decomposed into three yellow circles (called $0$, $1$, and $2$ mod $3$, if you like).  Each of those is decomposed into three green circles (according to mod $9$).  Each of those is decompolsed into three blue circles (according to mod $27$).  Further subdivisions are not shown in the picture.  You have to imagine them.

Topologically, $\mathbb Z_p$ is a Cantor set.

What about the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_p$?  For that we have to go upward as well as downward.  The gray circle, together with two more just like it make up a larger circle; $3$-adic numbers with a terms up to a $3^{-1}$ term.  Then three of those make a still larger circle; the $3$-adic numbers with terms up to a $3^{-2}$ term.  And so on upward.  Of course a $3$-adic number has $3^{-N}$ terms for only finitely many $N$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the image was created by Heiko Knospe, see third link in my comment to the question, and one should reference that source.

Comment: Thanks for the source.  I searched "fractal p-adic" on Google, and found this image, but no real source given.  [It was a reddit.com essay called "Any relation between pantheism, psychedelics and fractals? : pantheism"]